# How that list is appending the tuples in adjacency list method in if-else block?

Tags: python, list, graph

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.edges = []

class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, value, node_from, node_to):
        self.value = value
        self.node_from = node_from
        self.node_to = node_to

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, nodes=[], edges=[]):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.edges = edges

    def insert_node(self, new_node_val):
        new_node = Node(new_node_val)
        self.nodes.append(new_node)
        
    def insert_edge(self, new_edge_val, node_from_val, node_to_val):
        from_found = None
        to_found = None
        for node in self.nodes:
            if node_from_val == node.value:
                from_found = node
            if node_to_val == node.value:
                to_found = node
        if from_found == None:
            from_found = Node(node_from_val)
            self.nodes.append(from_found)
        if to_found == None:
            to_found = Node(node_to_val)
            self.nodes.append(to_found)
        new_edge = Edge(new_edge_val, from_found, to_found) 
        from_found.edges.append(new_edge)
        to_found.edges.append(new_edge)
        self.edges.append(new_edge)
```

Get Edge list

```
    def get_edge_list(self):
        """Don't return a list of edge objects!
        Return a list of triples that looks like this:
        (Edge Value, From Node Value, To Node Value)"""
        edge_list = []
        for edge in self.edges:
            edge_add = (edge.value, edge.node_from.value, edge.node_to.value)
            edge_list.append(edge_add)
        return edge_list
```

Get Adjacency list

```
    def get_adjacency_list(self):

    """Don't return any Node or Edge objects!
       You'll return a list of lists.
       The indices of the outer list represent
       "from" nodes.Each section in the list will store a list
       of tuples that looks like this:(To Node, Edge Value)"""

        max_index = self.find_max_index()
        adjacency_list = [None] * (max_index + 1)
        
        for edge_object in self.edges:
            tuple = (edge_object.node_to.value, edge_object.value)
            from_node = edge_object.node_from.value
```

how this part of the code is working?

I haven't seen list appending like variable from_node is value than how it's appending list can anyone explain with a simple example.

Like list = [None, None, None, None] then how it's appending say 2nd None in output with reference to code.

```
            if adjacency_list[from_node]:
                adjacency_list[from_node].append(tuple)
            else:
                adjacency_list[from_node] = [tuple]
        return adjacency_list
  
    
    def get_adjacency_matrix(self):
        """Return a matrix, or 2D list.
        Row numbers represent from nodes,
        column numbers represent to nodes.
        Store the edge values in each spot,
        and a 0 if no edge exists."""
        return []
    
    def find_max_index(self):
        max_index = -1
        if len(self.nodes):
            for node in self.nodes:
                if node.value > max_index:
                    max_index = node.value
        return max_index

graph = Graph()
graph.insert_edge(100, 1, 2)
graph.insert_edge(101, 1, 3)
graph.insert_edge(102, 1, 4)
graph.insert_edge(103, 3, 4)
# Should be [(100, 1, 2), (101, 1, 3), (102, 1, 4), (103, 3, 4)]
print graph.get_edge_list()
# Should be [None, [(2, 100), (3, 101), (4, 102)], None, [(4, 103)], None]
print graph.get_adjacency_list()
# Should be [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 100, 101, 102], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 103], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
print graph.get_adjacency_matrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

`from_node` is an integer.  You created the graph with integers for the node numbers.  The code sets up `adjacency_list` as an array of "None" values, as large as the largest node number:

```
        adjacency_list = [None] * (max_index + 1)
```

During the loop, it creates a tuple of information for that node.  (And by the way, it's bad practice to give a variable the same name as a built-in type.)  It wants to store that in element `from_node` of that list, but it can only do so if there is already a list there.  So

```
            if adjacency_list[from_node]:
                adjacency_list[from_node].append(tuple)
            else:
                adjacency_list[from_node] = [tuple]
```

If there is already a list in that element, we append the tuple to the list.  Otherwise, we create a new list containing only our tuple.

So, start with `[None, None, None, None, None]`.  Let's say we're doing node 1.  We create `tuple` with (2,100).  In the `if` statement, `adjacency_list[1]` is `None`, so we take the `else` clause and store a list with one element (`[(2,100)]`), so `adjacency_list` now contains `[None, [(2,100)], None, None, None]`.  Next time through the loop, the value of `tuple` is (3,101).  Since `adjacency_list` now contains something, we take the `if` clause, and just append the tuple to the list that's already there.  That creates `[None, [(2,100),(3,101)], None, None, None]`.